# Carthage errors "No tagged versions found for github"

Tags: carthage, haneke

I want to use Carthage in my projects, so I installed Carthage. I prepared a Cartfile in the project's root folder. When I typed the `carthage update` command in the terminal, I got this error:

> *** Cloning HanekeSwift
>   No tagged versions found for github "Haneke/HanekeSwift"

The Cartfile file contains these lines:

```
github "Alamofire/Alamofire" >= 1.2
github "Haneke/HanekeSwift"
```

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 30):

If the project has no tags, then you need to give it a branch or a ref.

```
github "Haneke/HanekeSwift" "master"
```

For instance.

Comment: I already tried it but i got this error        =              Parse error: empty pinned version in line: github "Haneke/HanekeSwift" ""

Comment: `github "Haneke/HanekeSwift" ""` should be `github "Haneke/HanekeSwift" "master"` ?

Comment: it is  = github "Haneke/HanekeSwift" "master" .  After I carthage update command i get = Parse error: empty pinned version in line: github "Haneke/HanekeSwift" ""

Comment: oh, strange. Is that the only thing in your Cartfile? Not a carthage pro, it /might/ be worth deleting the Carthage directory and starting over. It smells like it's got the "" cached somehow....

Comment: first i installed carthage pkg file and then i installed it on homebrew i think that causes the problem, i uninstalled both of them, deleted installing directories and deleted every register about installation of pkg and installed again via hombrew, but even this didnt solve the problem :) but thanks anyway for the answers ;)

Answer (score 2):

Even when specifying the specific branch or ref, Carthage (before 0.17.1) required that the repository has at least one semantic version tag, e.g.:

```
git tag 0.1
git push --tags
```

See the carthage documentation for details on how version numbers are interpreted: https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage#tag-stable-releases

Comment: Incorrect, as of 0.17.1 tags are not required if the branch is specified per Kaolin Fire's answer

Comment: 0.17.1 was released "5 days ago", this is four months old and result of an annoying debugging process.